# Adding Angular to Requirejs application is displaying Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

Im trying to add AngularJS to my web application which already makes use of RequireJS. I have followed a couple of YouTube and web tutorials but for some reason, when loading my test page, i am seeing:

```
1) Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=%5B%.....

2) TypeError: Modernizr is undefined
if (!Modernizr.history) {

3) For some reason jQuery has stopped working too.
```

Here's my tree:

```
resources
   - CSS
   - js
        - controllers
             - MainController.js
        - libs
             - angular.js
             - jquery.js
             - require.js
             - mondernizr.js
             ......
             ......
             ......
        main.js
        app.js
pages
        test.html
```

**main.js**

```
(function(require) {
'use strict';

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/resources/js',
    paths: {
        'jquery'    : 'libs/jquery',
        'angular'   : 'libs/angular',
        'router'    : 'libs/page',
        'history'   : 'libs/history.iegte8',
        'event'     : 'libs/eventemitter2'
    },
    shim: {
        'zepto'     : { exports: '$' },
        'angular'   : { exports : 'angular' },
        'router'    : { exports: 'page'}
    }
});



require([
    'controllers/MainController'
]);

})(this.require);
```

**app.js**

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {
return angular.module('MyApp', []);
})
```

**MainController.js**

```
require(['app'], function(app) {
    app.controller('MainController', function() {
        this.message = "Hello World";
    })
});
```

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Test</title>
</head>
    <body>        
        <div ng-controller="MainController as main">
            {{ main.message }}
        </div>    

        <script src="/resources/js/libs/require.js" data-main="/resources/js/main"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Using  AngularJS v1.2.16

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE** **********************************************

Have added `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular-route.js"></script>` to my test.html page and the `Error: [$injector...` error has disappeared.

Only error now showing is:

```
TypeError: Modernizr is undefined

if (!Modernizr.history) {
```

Followed advice on here: http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/error-injectornomod-module-ngroute-is-not-available/

Answer (score 1):

I went over to Modernizr's site and checked the code. I see that it does not call `define` to define itself as a module so Modernizr is not AMD-compliant and you need a shim for it to tell RequireJS what the module value should be:

```
shim: {
    ...
    modernizr: { exports: 'Modernizr' }
}
```

Comment: added your suggestion above, still getting the error.